# how to show audio equalizer in my android music app?

Tags: android

I am working on my first android app which is a music app and I need to provide equalizer for my app on menu options .. just tell how to use android equalizer class in my app ?

Answer (score 1):

To create visualizer :
1. Use canvas 
2. Draw rectangular shape according to your sound
3. Change color of your shapes.

You can also use below tutorials:
 https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer

It will help.

And if you want a demo of music player then you can follow below tutorial:

1. https://github.com/psaravan/JamsMusicPlayer
2. https://github.com/punker76/simple-music-player
3. https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid

Comment: This Was not so Helpful Because i wanted to add An equalizer Not A Visualizer .. But JamsMusicPlayer  Source Code Would Help ...